# Programmatically create models

Tags: cad, sketchup, autodesk, solidworks

I want to create a CAD model for the purpose of finding its properties like  mass, CG, inertia etc.
I want to do this programmatically because I have to vary the model slightly and get the new properties many times
What CAD software should I look into? maybe Inventor, Solidworks, FreeCAD, Sketchup (Pro or Make?)

Thanks

Comment: what kind of models you'd like to design? if it's mechanical design -SolidWorks, Inventor should be good for this. SketchUp is good to architectural prototyping.

Comment: Not sure what the other applications offer, but SketchUp Make (gives pretty much access to the same features as Pro in the Ruby API). It will give you volume for solids, but for CG, inertia etc you need to calculate that yourself. But it's using Ruby so development is quick and easy.

Comment: Solidworks has good parametric table-driven model capabilities. I'd go with that (but then I'm biased because I already have a license). :D